# javascript loops rating

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

i'm trying to loop 5 time html code and inside this loop trying to add color variable only number of the rating times.

maybe another loop after html?
please give an idea maybe there is other better way todo this

```
Template7.registerHelper('rating', function(options) {
    var rating = this.avgrating;
    var color = 'color-orange'; 
    var html ="";
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        html += '<i class="fa fa-star ' + color + '"></i>';
    }
    return html;
});
```

i m assuming var rating value 3 return html should return like this

```
 <i class="fa fa-star color-orange"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-star color-orange"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-star color-orange"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Template7.registerHelper('rating', function(options) {
    var rating = this.avgrating;
    var color = 'color-orange'; 
    var html ="";
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if(i <= rating){
        html += '<i class="fa fa-star ' + color + '"></i>';
        }else{
        html += '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
        }
    }
    return html;
});
```

you can check if condition to get the desired result.

Comment: imo more readable, since you don't duplicate the template: `for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){  html += '<i class="fa fa-star ' + (i < rating? color: '') + '"></i>'; }`

Comment: thank you.even more `Template7.registerHelper('rating', function(options) {
  var html ='';
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    html += '<i class="fa fa-star ' + (i < this.avgrating ? 'color-orange': '') + '"></i>';
  }
  return html;
});`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a loop is the best solution for this. When you put 2  for loops inside each other, then that is called a **nested for loop**